# how to display decrypt text in web

Tags: php, oracle, encryption

hye. i've successfully encrypt the sensitive data in my database. Now i want to decrypt the data and display it on the web. i've try this code but i got an error. can you help me?

```
<?php

// Connects to the XE service (i.e. database) on the "localhost" machine
   $conn = oci_connect('DEVELOPER', 'xs2developer', 'localhost/XE');


if (!$conn) {
$e = oci_error();
trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query1 = "SELECT *,enc_dec.decrypt(DATA_FYP) AS DECRYPT_DATA FROM FYP WHERE   ID_USER='".$id."'";

        $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query1);
         oci_execute($stid);

echo "<form name='form1' method='post' action=' '>";    
echo "<table align='center'>";


while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))
{   
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><b> Hostname : </b></td>";
    echo "<td width='100'><input type='text' name='HOST_NAME' size='30' value=' " . $row['HOST_NAME'] . " ' /></td>"; 
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><b> IP Address : </b></td>";
    echo "<td width='100'><input type='text' name='IP_ADDRESS' size='30' value= ' ".$row['IP_ADDRESS']. " '/></td>"; 
echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><b> Last Login : </b></td>";
    echo "<td width='100'><input name='LAST_LOGIN' type='text' size='30' value=' " .$row['LAST_LOGIN'] . " ' /> </td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><b> Data : </b></td>";
    echo "<td width='100'><textarea name='DATA_FYP' rows='10' cols='25'>".$row['DECRYPT_DATA']."</textarea></td>"; 
    echo "</tr>";


    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><b> Date : </b></td>";
    echo "<td width='100'><input name='DATE_REG' type='text' size='30' value=' " .$row['DATE_REG'] . " ' /> </td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
   echo "<td align='center'><input type='submit' name='Analyze' value='Analyze'></td>";



echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</form>";
echo "</table>";    


?>
```

and this is my database.

[image]

and this is an error that i got.
[image]

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @MartinDinov i've added the eror that i've got

Comment: @AlexPoole, 

$stid = oci_parse($conn, $query1);
 oci_execute($stid);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's nothing directly to do with your decrypt function. ou can't use `*` on its own and include another column (including a calculated or fixed value as a psuedo-column) unless you specify the table or its alias. This gets the same error:

```
select *, x as y from dual;
Error at Command Line : 2 Column : 9
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

But this is OK:

```
select d.*, x as y from dual d;
```

So you need to have:

```
    $query1 = "SELECT FYP.*,enc_dec.decrypt(DATA_FYP) AS DECRYPT_DATA FROM FYP WHERE   ID_USER='".$id."'";
```

or

```
    $query1 = "SELECT f.*,enc_dec.decrypt(f.DATA_FYP) AS DECRYPT_DATA FROM FYP f WHERE f.ID_USER='".$id."'";
```

Using `select *` is discouraged anyway; it is clearer if you explicitly list the columns you need and the order they should be in. It doesn't appear to make much practical difference here, but if more columns were added to the table you'd be pulling data you don't use, and in other circumstances (e.g. using positional rather than named variables) you could get errors. Specifying the columns is a good habit to get into, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

is used to give the data of all the columns in the table so u cannot use

```
SELECT *,column_name from TABLE;
```

Change the below line by using an alias for the table

```
  $query1 = "SELECT A.*,enc_dec.decrypt(A.DATA_FYP) AS DECRYPT_DATA FROM FYP A WHERE    ID_USER='".$id."'";
```